# Why install from a tarball when packaged option exists?

Tags: tar, rpm

If given the option to install software on CentOS or RHEL from an RPM, why would one ever still chose to install from a tarball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you want a different version than is available in the package manager.

From a security perspective, you might not trust a package manager, and so want to download the tarball, review the source, and install once you are confident it is not compromised.

Or you may want to edit the source to make the application behave differently, for example to resolve a bug.

Answer (score 2):

First, not all programs ever written are packaged as `rpm`. Secondly, if by `install from rpm` you mean tools such as `yum` or `zypper` and by `install by tarball` you mean downloading a tarball source code from a project's website and building and installing it manually there may be several reasons why someone would prefer to go with a `tarball` instead of a prepared package:

- to have a newest version of the given program that has not been yet prepared by a package maintainer
- to use some custom build options (for example at `./configure` step)

Lastly, sometimes you want just want to give a development version a try and not necessarily install it - non-stable versions are usually not packaged by package maintainers so there is no other way to try them.

Comment: This answer highlights an important distinction that could perhaps warrant being illuminated further: generally speaking, as the terms are often used (but the OP doesn't specify which), **the two operations are not equivalent.**